GoRoutines not in main end up in deadlock
I've been writing Go for a while, but just recently needed to actually utilize goroutines/asynchronous actions. I'm having a hard time understanding how things are supposed to work.

I have a main function, which is just the entry point to my cli tool (so it just runs cmd.ExecuteContext() and checks for an error).
I have a command, project doSomething, that needs to run some go routines in a for loop.
I am not exactly sure what the issue is, I've hit: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! but when I think I've solved that my command just seems to hang forever (I think this happens when one of the go routines hits an error...?).

Can someone help me understand the pattern I am supposed to implement here?
main.go
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    if err := cmd.NewRootCommand().ExecuteContext(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Err(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

anotherfile.go
func NewRootCommand() *cobra.Command {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(newProjectCmd())
    return rootCmd
}

func newProjectCmd() *cobra.Command {
    projCmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "project",
        Short: "Interact with groups",
    }
    projCmd.AddCommand(newDoSomethingCmd())
    return projCmd
}

func newDoSomethingCmd() *cobra.Command {
    cmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "doSomething",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            
            // stuff happens here, but no go routines or anything.

            err := project.DoSomething(cmd.Context())
            if err != nil {
                os.Exit(1)
            }
        },
    }
    return cmd
}

lastfile.go (the project package)
func DoSomething(ctx context.Context) error {
        // lots of stuff happens
        err := firstFunction(ctx) 
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
}

func firstFunction(ctx context.Context) error {
        // stuff here no go routines
        err := functionWithGoRoutines(ctx) 
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // gets called multiple times with different parameters -- at this point I want the above to FINISH though before moving on to here
        err := functionWithGoRoutines(ctx) 
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
}

// UPDATED
func functionWithGoRoutines(ctx context.Context, items []string) error {
    errors := make(chan error, 0)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, item := range items {
        wg.Add(1)
        i := item
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            out, err := doSomethingToItemThatCanReturnError(ctx, i)
            if err != nil {
                errors <- fmt.Errorf("erro: %v", err)
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(out)
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(errors)

    var err error
    if len(errors) > 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("multiple errors occurred: %v", errors)
    }
    return err
}

Please let me know if this is already answered somewhere else and I missed it! From what I could tell, nothing was describing my situation exactly. Also please let me know if anything is unclear about what I am trying to do!
My end goal is to have a function which loops through a slice, and starts a go routine for each item in the slice. I want each item's go routine to have time to finish before exiting the outer function. I want to collect the errors (if any) and return them once all the go routines have finished.
I also tried creating the wait group in main.go, and passing it all the way through to my function. I saw somewhere i should declare it globally... but wasn't sure where?
UPDATE
@Burak Sedar solve my original question but I realized that in my code I have one more issue/consideration.
Inside each of the above go routines is another go routine that needs to run, but this one does not return an error and should just run in the background until the "outer" go routine finishes. Then it can just be cancelled.
I'm doing this, but it seems to take over the wait for the outer go routine and causes the whole command to never end:
go func() {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return
    default:
        time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
        doSomethingNewThatShouldEndOnceOuterRoutineEnds(ctx)
    }
    return
}()



You did not initialize the wg.

typo! I fixed it. :) i initialize the wg. right above the for loop.

What @BurakSerdar said. Also note that var WG *sync.WaitGroup looks suspicious: while in itself it's nothing bad to have a pointer to a variable, in this case you do not have the variable to point to, so the WG is initialized to nil. You quite possibly wanted to just have var wg sync.WaitGroup to have a variable of type sync.WaitGroup, and then pass around a pointer to it by taking its address using the & operator–like &wg. You probably need a refresher on pointers.

May be start with this part of the Tour: https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/1

That's fair! If I remove the pointer and initialize it just as var sync.WaitGroup inside the function, I'm not sure where I would pass the &wg to (since it's used just inside the function I initialize it in).

Just use var wg sync.WaitGroup. No need for a pointer.

«I'm not sure where I would pass the &wg to»–in your very particular case there's no need to pass it around. But as with any low-level synchronization primitives, you must not copy sync.WaitGroup once you've started using it (say, called Add on it). So, should you need to pass it to another call–which happens in real-world code–you must pass a pointer to it (an address of it), not the value of wg itself. That's what I tried to highlight. Please make youself accustomed with the concept of values, variables (storing values) and pointers. They are all different–however related–concepts.

@BurakSerdar I udpated my functionsWithGoRoutines code above. I ran that and it hangs indefinitely (but I'm pretty sure it's hitting an error in doSomethingToItemThatCanReturnError.

Your code will hang if an error happens, because the goroutine where error happens will block trying to write to the error channel. There are no goroutines reading from it.
You have to put either waiting on the waitgroup or listening to the error channel to its own goroutine:
func functionWithGoRoutines(ctx context.Context, items []string) error {
    errors := make(chan error, 0)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, item := range items {
        wg.Add(1)
        i := item
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            out, err := doSomethingToItemThatCanReturnError(ctx, i)
            if err != nil {
                errors <- fmt.Errorf("erro: %v", err)
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(out)
        }()
    }

    go func() {
       wg.Wait()
       close(errors)
    }()

    errs:=make([]error,0)
    for err:=range errors {
       errs=append(errs,err)
    }
    if len(errs)==0 {
       return nil
    }

    return errors.Join(errs...)
}


Thank you this is exactly what I needed! I have one more question...
What if I wanted to start another go routine before the doSomethineToItemThatCanReturnError and:

That go routine will never return an error
That go routine just needs to run until the "outer" go routine is finished.


Then do just that: start a new goroutine in the goroutine, and defer close a channel in the outer goroutine that the inner goroutine checks for termination.
